# Python3 - transform a complex string to a list/dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a string like this one:

```
l1="[{'t_steps': '', 't_expected': '', 't_type': 'Functional', 't_precond': 'xxx', 't_notes': 'test note', 't_name': 'First test'}]"
```

I need to transform it to a real list object like:

```
l1=[{'t_steps': '', 't_expected': '', 't_type': 'Functional', 't_precond': 'xxx', 't_notes': 'test note', 't_name': 'First test'}]
```

I tried:

```
l1=list(l1)
```

or

```
l1=l1.split(',')
```

But the result is not good.
Please can someone help me to convert my string to a form that python can read?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: `import ast; l1 = ast.literal_eval(string)`

Answer (score 3):

use `eval`

```
l1="[{'t_steps': '', 't_expected': '', 't_type': 'Functional', 't_precond': 'xxx', 't_notes': 'test note', 't_name': 'First test'}]"
```

do this:

```
l1 = eval(l1)
l1
```

output:

```
[{'t_steps': '', 't_expected': '', 't_type': 'Functional', 't_precond': 'xxx', 't_notes': 'test note', 't_name': 'First test'}]
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, the problem is when the string contain a null value like this: '[{"tk_kval": "yyy", "tk_kgroup": null, "tk_descr": "Create key", "t_owner": 1}]'

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean，can u explain?

Comment: if u run l1=eval('[{"tk_kval": "yyy", "tk_kgroup": null, "tk_descr": "Create key", "t_owner": 1}]') you got an error because null value

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using `json`:

```py
import json

l1="[{'t_steps': '', 't_expected': '', 't_type': 'Functional', 't_precond': 'xxx', 't_notes': 'test note', 't_name': 'First test'}]"
l2 = json.loads(l1)
```

Comment: This won't work. The JSON should use ```"``` instead of ```'``` for this to work. You can use ```l1.replace("'","\"")``` but this will be a hack instead of an actual solution.

Comment: Well, yeah, thanks for pointing out. Need to replace the single quotes for double ones first. To me it still looks more natural than evaluation via ast (which does seem a dirty hack). But tastes differ!

Comment: There is a built-in available ```eval``` that does the same job as pointed out by @xiutiqianshi

Answer (score 0):

Here in code you can parse.

```
x = "[{'t_steps': '', 't_expected': '', 't_type': 'Functional', 't_precond': 'xxx', 't_notes': 'test note', 't_name': 'First test'}]"
import re
# remove the [] and {} from the string
x = x.replace('[',"").replace("]","").replace("{","").replace("}","")
# split the string considering ',' and ite will return a list
x = x.split(",")
new_dict ={}
for values in x:
    # remove the "'" from the string
    values = re.sub("'*", '', values)
    values = values.replace('"', '')
    # split the key value pair from the list ':' and
    key, value = values.split(":")
    key = key.strip()
    value = value.strip()
    if value == "null":
        value = None
    else:
        # parsing the string value ton int or float
        try:
            if "." in value:
                value = float(value)
            else:
                value = int(value)
        except:
            pass
    new_dict[key.strip()] = value
final_list = []
final_list.append(new_dict)
print(final_list)
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, the problem is when the string contain a null value like this: '[{"tk_kval": "yyy", "tk_kgroup": null, "tk_descr": "Create key", "t_owner": 1}]'

Comment: @ManuelSanti I have updated the answer. Please check. Thank you.